# Solr path to index directory

Tags: search, solr, configuration, indexing, config

We have a remote server with a Solr configuration running on it. Now I want with https://code.google.com/p/luke/ check which data is indexed.

The given tool asks for the 'Path to Index directory'. My question is, where can I find it, where is it configured? I cannot find it (for as far as I know/have seen) in the solrconfig.xml or the schema.xml

Someone who know's how to help me?

Kind regards,

Pim

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a [more recent version of Luke](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke). And the index directory is normally the *data* directory on the same level as the *conf* directory which is where you found your *schema.xml*.

You can also see what's been indexed field-by-field in the AdminUI on the [Schema Browser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+Browser+Screen) screen.